# Does the Shi function has an inverse? and if so, how could I obtain it?

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

By the Shi function I refer to the hyperbolic sine integral $$\operatorname{Shi}(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sinh (t)}{t} d t,$$
and I was wondering how could I obtain its inverse, if possible.

Comment: Of course, the fact that the inverse _exists_ is clear from the fact that the integrand $\frac{\sinh (t)}{t}$ is strictly positive for all $t$.

Answer (score 6):

You need to carry out three steps.

1. Expand $\sinh t$ with a Taylorseries (has infinite radius of convergence => can be integrated):
   $$\dfrac{\sinh t}{t}=1+\dfrac{t^2}{3!}+\dfrac{t^4}{5!}+\dfrac{t^6}{7!}+\ldots$$
2. Integrate the expanded integrand :
   $$\text{Shi}(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \left[1+\dfrac{t^2}{3!}+\dfrac{t^4}{5!}+\dfrac{t^6}{7!}+\ldots \right]dt=x+\dfrac{x^3}{3\cdot 3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5\cdot 5!}+\dfrac{x^7}{7\cdot 7!}+\ldots$$
3. Invoke [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Answer (score 5):

Doing what @MachineLearner answered and using series reversion if
$$y=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sinh (t)}{t} dt$$ you will get something like
$$x=y+\frac 1{18}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n\, y^{2n+1}$$ where the first $a_n$ make the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{41}{300},\frac{6407}{264600},\frac{1390567}{285768000},\frac{1093170077}{1037337840000},\frac{52976512541047}{220890719649600000
   },\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: So it is implicit in these answers that $\operatorname{Shi}^{-1}(y)$ probably cannot be written as a "finite" expression in "standard" mathematical functions?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen. This is correct